# Decrypting using Go a string encrypted in php using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256

Tags: php, encryption, go, aes

In PHP, `mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);` returns a value of 32, thus apparently saying that AES-256 wants an Initialization Vector of 32 bytes. But this is deceiving, as said in the [comments for `mcrypt_encrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#117667):

> Also, `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is not AES-256, it's a different variant of the Rijndael block cipher. If you want AES-256 in mcrypt, you have to use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` with a 32-byte key. OpenSSL makes it more obvious which mode you are using (i.e. 'aes-128-cbc' vs 'aes-256-ctr').

So of course, with an IV of 32 bytes, the following example does not work in Go (it causes a panic).

```
score := decodePost(c.PostForm("score"))
iv := decodePost(c.PostForm("iv"))

aesKey := getAESKey()
baseAES, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(aesKey))
if err != nil {
    c.AbortWithError(500, err)
    return
}
block := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(baseAES, []byte(iv))
block.CryptBlocks(score, score)
```

Quoting from the docs of `crypto/cipher`:

> The length of iv must be the same as the Block's block size and must match the iv used to encrypt the data.

(And of course, the [AES block size in Go is 16 bytes](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/aes/#pkg-constants)).

So, finally, how can I decrypt such string in Go?

Comment: Of course the best solution is to change the Rijndael block size to 128-bits on the other side and eliminate interoperability issues now and in the future.

Comment: That would be ideal, but unfortunately I can't do that because I don't have control of the other side (and there is no easy way for me to gain it).

Comment: Rijndael-256, as quite clearly stated, isn't AES. It's Rijndael. You need an implementation of this for your go code. The reason you need a 32 byte IV is because the block size of Rijndael-256 is 256 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Since in Golang you have only built-in standard AES crypto, you need to implement the Rijndael crypto yourself.

I found one here: https://github.com/celso-wo/rijndael256/blob/master/rijndael256.go

Answer (score 0):

Several years later, I've been told by a colleague of mine which stumbled upon this issue again that this gist is a good implementation of the algorithm, while alas the one posted by itscaro didn't seem to work:

https://gist.github.com/slifer2015/0d182d99280758a154e3fe12e48664d4

This is essentially the code from the Go `crypto/aes` library, adjusted to use the 32 byte IV and Rijnadael256 algorithm.

As I've not yet had the time to verify this solution myself I will not yet accept this solution, though if I have time I'll write some tests to make sure that the code does manage to encrypt/decrypt precisely as the PHP implementation.

Just as a warning: **always read carefully crypto code you find on the internet,** and please only use this algorithm if you do find yourself as well in need of supporting it to decode data outside of your control. For normal symmetric and asymmetric encryption, the go `crypto` packages provide safe and battle-tested well-supported cryptographic solutions such as RSA, Ed25519 and AES.